# Meaning of 'no earlier than X days after Y'

Tags: negation

I am having trouble understanding the following notice on the American Airlines AAdvantage (miles account) [website](https://www.aa.com/AAdvantage/requestMileageCreditAccess.do):

> Note: Mileage credit requests can be submitted no earlier than 15 days
>   after all travel is completed.

What does it exactly mean? Which of the following statements is the correct interpretation?

1. I have to wait for 15 days after all my travel is completed before I can request my mileage credit
2. If I want to request my mileage credit, I have to do so within 15 days after my travel is completed
3. Something else

In any case, I wonder, is the original statement grammatically correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement

> Mileage credit requests can be submitted no earlier than 15 days after
>   all travel is completed

means you must wait for 15 days to do the submission and *cannot do it earlier*.

The statement

> Mileage credit requests can be submitted no later than 15 days after
>   all travel is completed

means you must do the submission within 15 days and *cannot do it later*.

Both statements here are grammatically correct (and mean different things).