# Not earlier than 15 minutes

Tags: meaning

Please arrive at the venue not earlier than 15 minutes before the commencement of the interview.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning of 'no earlier than X days after Y'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33910/meaning-of-no-earlier-than-x-days-after-y)

Comment: If you get there 16 minutes before the interview, they set your application on fire. Well, I'm guessing that's what they do. Something bad happens, anyway. But I'm guessing  your application goes up in flames. Or they tow your car. Or, their bouncer will throw you out. Whatever it is, don't risk it. I don't really know, however; they didn't tell me what will happen. I can only guess. That's what happens when someone doesn't give me all he facts. But I think you should stay away. Definitely. Until exactly 15 minutes before the interview. 14 minutes sounds safe.

Comment: Please read that once again. The authors of the instructions had meant 'not later than' instead.

Comment: I may be wrong but I would have said 'arrive...no earlier than 15 minutes', rather than 'not earlier'.  Would that have made it clearer? I think it may depend on whether one regards 'earlier' as an adverb or a noun here. It would be interesting to have the view of a grammarian.

Comment: @WS2: Right. It's ***no** earlier than 15 minutes before the event.*

Comment: @tchrist I'm interested that several august contributors, in their wisdom, have closed this on the basis that it can be answered 'with commonly-available references'. Where exactly would one have found, 'commonly-available', the contribution that John Lawler made?

Comment: @WS2 Me too. The OP asked a question, they tagged it with _meaning_, the minor edit that was made was to insert two spaces. There are three real answers plus medica has provided an answer in the comments but voted to close. Kris didn't understand the term at all and yet has voted to close. There's nothing on my search of Google that is a 'reference' (unless Yahoo answers count) on the first page. If it's a duplicate then it's a duplicate, but not off-topic. The help page says it's OK to ask about 'Word choice and usage', this is _usage_ isn't it, _used like this ... what is the meaning_ .

Comment: @Frank - I closed it only because it is a dupe. :( But it's a very common question hereabouts. I've seen it a ton of times.

Comment: @medica Why wasn't it closed as a duplicate? If it's a duplicate it can't be _off-topic_. I realise that sounds pedantic but this is EL&U and it seems to me that's exactly what it's predicated on. As with WS2, I don't agree that the meaning of 'not earlier than X' would be found in commonly-available references to the layman which presumably the OP is - or is that what makes it off topic is that it has not been asked by a linguist, etymologist or a serious English language enthusiast, that would surely mean all questions are off-topic unless you include your credentials in the question.

Comment: @medica Just out of interest, I look in the _commonly-available references_ that are listed here http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available-online not one of them has a definition for _not earlier than_, one had a definition for _no sooner than_ but it was the wrong one. Perhaps you can ask your fellow on-holders which _commonly_available references_ this definition can be found in and to update the list.

Comment: @Frank - a dictionary will define *earlier*, *not* and *than*. I just looked it up and found an answer in about 7 seconds. If it can be found with minimal effort, it's OT. To be honest, the entire post was OT because there wasn't even a question (which is usually mandatory), and people are supposed to share the work they've done. Which is why I commented in frustration about *guessing...guessing...guess*. I'm not a mod, just a member like yourself. If you feel strongly about it, please post a question in Meta. But I would close it again on any of those grounds.

Comment: @medica It's easy for you to look up a dictionary of three words, put them together and understand what _not earlier than_ means because you already know what it means. Neither you nor I need a dictionary or any reference to know what it means. You knew exactly what the OP was asking, you found a duplicate and answered in mere moments. I could take up the reason for closure in Meta but it'll just be yet another 'why is this closed' with same old non-answers so I'll probably not bother but thanks for responding in this particular case.

Comment: @Frank _Not earlier than_ means exactly what the elements that make up the phrase mean. Nothing more, nothing less. How is that not off-topic as General Reference? I don't recall seeing a question before that, like this one, could reasonably be closed for _all_ of the available closing reasons. It fits every single one.

Answer (score 2):

In plain English, *do not arrive more than 15 minutes early for your interview*.

Answer (score 1):

"Not earlier than" means *later*, i.e. you can arrive 15 minutes before the interview or later. Five or ten minutes before the interview, for instance.

Comment: +1 In a individual case this could be "_Your interview is at 12:30, please do not arrive at the venue BEFORE 12:15_". In the case of holding interviews it is designed to avoid individual interviewees from meeting each other.

Comment: Strictly speaking you could arrive late for the interview, and have complied with the instructions. If you care about making a good impression though, I wouldn't advise that.

Answer (score -1):

"Not earlier than X" means "after X".

"Not later than X" means "before X".